# How to filter a Kendo UI MVC grid using a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo grid that is filtered by pushing values from a dropdownlist into the built in kendo filters. I can search the grid using the same method when I type values in a textbox and search. This is my kendo grid and the dropdown

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.MyObject.ID)
           .Name("Objects").DataTextField("Value").DataValueField("Key")
           .BindTo(@Model.MyObjectList).AutoBind(true)
           .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "selectedObject" })
 <a class="button"  onclick="searchGrid()" id="search">Search</a>                       

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<MyViewModel>()
        .Name("MyGrid").HtmlAttributes(new { style = " overflow-x:scroll;" })
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
           columns.Bound(a => a.MyObject.Name).Title("Field 1");
            columns.Bound(a => a.Column2).Title("Field 2");
        }
        .Pageable(page => page.PageSizes(true))
        .Scrollable(src => src.Height("auto"))
        .Sortable()
        .Filterable()
        .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
        .ColumnMenu()
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(10)
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetList_Read", "MyController"))
        )
    )

  <script>
       function searchGrid()
       {
          selectedObject = $("#selectedObject").data("kendoDropDownList");

          gridFilter = = { filters: [] };

          if ($.trim(selectedRecipient).length > 0) {
        gridListFilter.filters.push({ field: "Field 1", operator: "eq", value: selectedObject});
    }
        }
    var grid = $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.dataSource.filter(gridFilter);
  </script>
```

My View model looks like

```
 public class MyViewModel
 {
    public MyObject myObj {get;set;}
    public string Column2 {get;set;}
 }
```

The above function work when the search field is a textbox but it doesnt work when I am using a dropdown. I think it is because I am pushing the id of 'MyObject' into the grid filter while the grid is populated with the name of 'MyObject'. Can anyone show me how I can fix this. Thank you!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways of handling this issue as I've found out. One is by pushing the selected values into the built in Kendo Filters or by passing a value to the controller action and filtering on the server side. First store the selected value of the dropdown on-change event to an object called 'selectedDropDownValue'

**Filtering Client Side (Pushing values to kendo filters)**

```
function searchGrid()
{
   var gridListFilter = { filters: [] };
   var gridDataSource = $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;

   gridListFilter.logic = "and";   // a different logic 'or' can be selected
    if ($.trim(selectedDropDownValue).length > 0) {
        gridListFilter.filters.push({ field: "MyObject.MyObjectID", operator: "eq", value: parseInt(selectedDropDownValue) });
    }

   gridDataSource.filter(gridListFilter);
   gridDataSource.read();
}
```

This pushes the selected value of the drop down to the built-in kendo grid filter

**Filtering Server-side**

Edit the DataSource read line by adding data

```
.Read(read => read.Action("GetApportionmentList_Read", "Apportionment").Data("AddFilter"))
```

Then create a javascript function to add the filter

```
function AddFilter()
{
   return {filter:selectedDropDownValue};
}
```

Then inside the search grid JS function start with

```
function searchGrid()
{
   var gridListFilter = { filters: [] };
   var gridDataSource = $("#MyGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource;
   gridDataSource.read();
 }
```

After the read call you can still add client-side filters, apply the filter and then make the read recall afterwards.
The contoller signature should look like this

```
 public JsonResult GetList_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, string filter)
```

filter will contain the value of the drop down selected

Answer (score 0):

In your filter you are setting

```
 value: selectedObject
```

but `selectedObject` is the actual Kendo DropDownList widget instance.
You need to get the value out of the widget using `.value()` or `.text()`

```
selectedObject = $("#selectedObject").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. That was kind of the issue although the I couldn't use the answer provided to solve the problem.