# Hide and Show rows of Kendo Grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-dropdown

I have a Kendo UI Grid for ASP.NET MVC and also dropdownlist.

All the data in grid has a one column same as data in Dropdownlist and I want to show only those rows as I have selected in Dropdownlist and hide others simultaneously as per selection show and hide, show and hide.

Dropdownlist:

[image]

Grid:

[image]

Here as per dropdownlist selection I want to hide and show the grid data like if I select PRP2016 Grid only show data of PRP2016 related and if choose PRP2017 I want to show data related to PRP2017 in grid and hide other data.

I don't know how to do it.

I have tried hide and show feature but not get the result.

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve sound more like a filtering rather then showing hidding fields. 
You can pass filter datasource with the selected value from dropdown.

A good starting point can be found here: [How to filter a Kendo UI MVC grid using a dropdown list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836382/how-to-filter-a-kendo-ui-mvc-grid-using-a-dropdown-list)